# r gathering multivariate time series

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, hierarchical

I have a data frame I want to convert to a time series. Problem is for each date I have multiple products. It looks like

```
    Name_Article Week Num_Any Spending Unit_Price
1      Product_A   1    2016   196.05     3.376000
2      Product_B   1    2016   377.04     1.004867
3      Product_A   2    2016  2979.40     3.376000
4      Product_C   2    2016   353.44     3.034444
5      Product_D   2    2016   160.99     0.653621
6      Product_E   2    2016   950.22     1.441164
7      Product_A   3    2016   196.05     3.376000
8      Product_B   3    2016   377.04     1.004867
9      Product_D   3    2016  2979.40     0.653621
10     Product_E   3    2016   353.44     1.441164
11     Product_A   4    2016   160.99     3.376000
12     Product_B   4    2016   950.22     1.441164
```

I know that working with weekly time series is not the best option, but I have no choice. My idea is to get something like

```
  Week Spending.A UnitPrice.A Spending.B UnitPrice.B Spending.C UnitPrice.C ...
    1      196.05    3.376000     377.04    1.004867        0.00   3.034444
    2     2979.40    3.376000       0.00    1.004867      353.44   3.034444
    3      120.05    3.376000     377.04    1.004867        0.00   3.950000
    4      160.99    3.500000     950.22    1.441164    ...
```

I can't get my head around the tydir functions `gather()` and `spread()`. Any help will be appreciated!

In case you were wondering, the goal of all this is to preform a hierarchical forecasting , but before I begin I need my data to be structurated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Your data is in long format - I think you should keep it that way. Going to a wide format as you show will make modeling more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove everything up to the underscore in `Name_Article` and drop the year column.  Then read it as a zoo object splitting by `Name_Article` and specifying the `Week` is the index.

If you need a specific form then various conversions are possible such as `as.ts(z)`, `fortify.zoo(z)`, `coredata(z)`, `index(z)` and `zoo(coredata(z))`.

```
library(zoo)

DF2 <- transform(DF, Name_Article = sub(".*_", "", Name_Article))[-3]
z <- read.zoo(DF2, index = "Week", split = "Name_Article", FUN = identity)
```

giving:

```
> z
  Spending.A Unit_Price.A Spending.B Unit_Price.B Spending.C Unit_Price.C
1     196.05        3.376     377.04     1.004867         NA           NA
2    2979.40        3.376         NA           NA     353.44     3.034444
3     196.05        3.376     377.04     1.004867         NA           NA
4     160.99        3.376     950.22     1.441164         NA           NA
  Spending.D Unit_Price.D Spending.E Unit_Price.E
1         NA           NA         NA           NA
2     160.99     0.653621     950.22     1.441164
3    2979.40     0.653621     353.44     1.441164
4         NA           NA         NA           NA
```

### Note

The data in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "
    Name_Article Week Num_Any Spending Unit_Price
1      Product_A   1    2016   196.05     3.376000
2      Product_B   1    2016   377.04     1.004867
3      Product_A   2    2016  2979.40     3.376000
4      Product_C   2    2016   353.44     3.034444
5      Product_D   2    2016   160.99     0.653621
6      Product_E   2    2016   950.22     1.441164
7      Product_A   3    2016   196.05     3.376000
8      Product_B   3    2016   377.04     1.004867
9      Product_D   3    2016  2979.40     0.653621
10     Product_E   3    2016   353.44     1.441164
11     Product_A   4    2016   160.99     3.376000
12     Product_B   4    2016   950.22     1.441164"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```